# Overriding Android ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to do a very simple thing. I have a listview in my application which I dynamically add text to. But, after a certain point, I would like to change the color of the text inside the listview. So, I made a XML defining my custom list item, and subclassed the ArrayAdapter. But, whenever I call the add() method on my custom ArrayAdapter, an item does get added to the listview, but the text is not placed into it.

Here's my XML: `

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/list_content" android:textSize="8pt"
    android:gravity="center" android:layout_margin="4dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#FF00FF00"/>
```

And my ArrayAdapter subclass:

```
private class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public View v;
    public customAdapter(Context context){  
        super(context, R.layout.gamelistitem);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        this.v = convertView;
        if(v==null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v=vi.inflate(R.layout.gamelistitem, null);
        }

        if(timeLeft!=0) {
            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
            //tv.setText(str[pos]);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else {
            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
            //tv.setText(str[pos]);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something horribly wrong, but I'm still a little new to Android.

Thank you!
`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set the text in `getView()`.  Get the value to set with `getItem(pos)`, then set it.

```
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    this.v = convertView;
    if(v==null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v=vi.inflate(R.layout.gamelistitem, null);
    }

    // Moved this outside the if blocks, because we need it regardless
    // of the value of timeLeft.
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
    tv.setText(getItem(pos));

    if(timeLeft!=0) {
        //TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
        //tv.setText(str[pos]);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else {
        //TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
        //tv.setText(str[pos]);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }

    return v;
}
```

Also, is there a reason you're storing `v` as a member variable, rather than just inside the function?

Comment: I was storing v because I thought I might need to override the add() method since my ListView starts with nothing in in but it gains objects over time.

Comment: @Brian515: Ah.  That's one of the nice things about extending a full-featured class like ArrayAdapter.  It already handles pretty much everything you need (like `add()`), and you can worry about just the odd bits like custom data or custom views.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to play around too much with ListView (I'm just starting out), but from my understanding of what you're doing and of how ListView works, I can see another potential problem.  As I understand, ListView recycles views, so if you're checking the value of timeLeft when the view is added, old items might change from green to red as the user scrolls up and down.  If that happens, perhaps consider using an object that contains both the String and the current timeLeft when it's created, rather than just String?

Comment: @erichamion Yeah, I'm having the problem where all the objects turn red once timeLeft equals 0. How do I overcome this? Can I have ListView not recycle the view?

Comment: @Brian: I'd probably use a small class that holds both the String and the current timeLeft value.  That would require an `Array<MyClass>` and extending from `ArrayAdapter<MyClass>`, but it would cause only minor changes to `getView()`.  If there's no way around calculating timeLeft within the adapter, an `add(String)` method could be added to create a new MyClass object (using the String and the current timeLeft) and call `add(MyClass)` (which would still not be overridden).  That way, you're recording when the _data_ is added, not when the _view_ is added.

Comment: ths actually overwrites the setDropDownViewResource