# Android pass data from ListView to Popup window

Tags: android, listview, popup

I was looking for a solution for my problem, but still can't figure it out. What I want to achieve?

1. I got a `Data` object, which represents data I am working with. Just a simple class with a few `String` variables, it also implements `Parcelable`.
2. I populate `Data` object with a external web service and got a `List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();` with results. I send this list to another `Activity`.
3. I got a `DataAdapter` which extends `ArrayAdapter<Data>` to view results, everything works fine, I just set my adapter and display results in `ListView`.

   data = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("data");

   dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_results_list,data);

   list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
4. Now things start to get tricky. On every list element I added a button

   ```
   Button... android:onClick="showPopup"
   ```

The `showPopup` method creates a `PopupWindow` and I inflate it with my layout.

```
LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_phones);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_phones, viewGroup);
```

My question and problem is: How to pass my data to that popup?? For example, I just want to pass some text from `Data` object associated with given `ListView` item and display it on my popup.

I can paste more code if you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to complete my task. Gunaseelan's answer was fine, but it didn't work with Button on my list, only with whole list item. I found a solution here:

http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/

I just need to create a custom onCLickListener and attach it in my custom Adapter. Then in onClick method I just create my popup, get the clicked button position and populate data.

```
private OnClickListener phonesListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_results);
        final int position = lv.getPositionForView(v);.... make whatever you need
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have convert the selected list item as collection object. Then you can convert it as a arraylist. Then you can access from that array list and populate the data to your popup. sample code :

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
        Collection<Object> str = mylist.get(arg2).values();
        ArrayList<Object> al1 = new ArrayList<Object>(str);

        LayoutInflater layout = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layout.inflate(R.layout.your_popup, null);

        popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        TextView tv3 = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        TextView tv4 = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        TextView tv5 = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);

        tv1.setText(al1.get(1));
        tv2.setText(al1.get(2));
        tv3.setText(al1.get(3));
        tv4.setText(al1.get(4));
        tv5.setText(al1.get(5));

        Button close = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.close);
        close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I hope this will help you.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this solution. I just got one question:
Collection<Object> str = mylist.get(arg2).values();
What is a mylist? I got a List with my Data objects, so is doesn't have a values() method.

Comment: mylist is a list that holds data for listview friend. In your case it is dataList I think so. check it friend.

Comment: Thats right, but what about 'values()'? How to create a Collection<Object> having my ArrayList<Data> dataList ?

Comment: see [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29) friend. values() is a method of collection interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine, but not 100% how I wanted to. Now if I click on a list item, a popup is displayed and I can show needed data. The problem is I wanted user to click on a button (which is on list), not on a whole list item. Is it possible to achieve with a little changes?

Comment: Yes frined. It is Possible. For you have to override you getview() method of your ListAdapter. Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177056/overriding-android-arrayadapter?answertab=votes#tab-top) friend.

Comment: If my answer is helpful you can accept it as a correct answer friend. Also you can upvote it as a useful answer.